# Using zeromq.js to communicate from a nodejs app with a python backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

I have a python program that will accept a ZeroMQ `REQ` Requester and provide a number of functionalities, based on the given code.

So if a client sends a code `02`, python will return back a memory statistics, `03` a CPU statistics and so on.

The client is created with `nodejs` and `zeromq.js`, in order to communicate with the backend. I am not sure what the best way would be to send multiple messages from the frontend, since I will send multiple such messages with different codes each second.

What I have now is something similar to this:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    var zmq = require('zeromq')
    , sock = zmq.socket('req');

    var con_string = ''

    app.post('/connect', function(req, res) {
        protocol = 'tcp';
        address = req.body.address;
        port = req.body.port;
        con_string = protocol + '://' + address + ':' + port;
        sock.connect(con_string);
        res.send('OK');
    });

    app.get('/workers', function(req, res) {
        sock.connect(con_string);
        sock.send(['client', 'echo', '02']); 
    });
};
```

By calling the `/workers` function I can see the first request arriving at my backend, but no more subsequent requests will arrive unless I restart the whole `nodejs` application.

Why is this happening, and also given that I want to send many messages, is there a better way of structuring my `nodejs` app, since I did not see any similar examples available on the ZeroMQ guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

ZeroMQ uses distributed actors-model for a sort of multi-party behaviour in each of their pre-defined Formal Scalable Communication Archetypes.

The **`REQ`** is just a one part of such multi-party distributed-behaviour.

The opposite and symmetrically cardinal and necessary part is the **`REP`** node.

The complete picture of this distributed-behavioural game ( called `REQ/REP` ) is this:

**`REQ`** asks,
**`REP`** replies ( yes, first has to receive and indeed read the message & then mus send an answer ),
**`REQ`** can only, after having `.recv()`-ed ( un-loaded ) such an answer from `REP`, go and ask again the `REP` for getting another reply...

This means, your code has to internally get aligned with this and coordinate it's local behaviour so as to meet this [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) behavioural game.

Ignoring these hardwired rules means a problem -- your **`REQ`**-side code n now seems, that it just remains inside its self-locked FSA-state ( wanting to send next messages ), where it simply somehow forgot to also `.recv()` the first and subsequent answers, that have ( or will have ) arrived from `REP`-side after the `REQ`'s first `.send()`, and thus the `REQ` will never be able again ( until the reset, as was explained above ) to `.send()` any "next"-message anymore to the `REP`-part.